# Alternative to VisionKit VNDocumentCameraViewController on Android Platform

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented the `VisionKit VNDocumentCameraViewController` that is used in the notes application on iPhone .. which works quite well. Takes several picture and then straitens them,  But I wonder if there is anything like this control for Android? I have tried to google it, I really have but I just can't find anything that work the same. Do you guys have some experience with this?

Comment: Vision is by far the best in my experience. It's offline too. I know of Tesseract (sometime slow) and Google Cloud Vision (Bad privacy), but I wouldn't recommend them.

Comment: did you manage to find something?